# Getting #<undef> back when calling a scheme function

Tags: scheme

I have the following code in Scheme:

```
(define (processExpression lst)
     (define operand (car lst))
     (define operator1 (cadr lst))
     (define operator2 (caddr lst))

     (if (list? operand) 
          (begin
             (display "Invalid syntax! Erroring out!")
             (quit)
         )
      )

      (if (and (number? operator1) (number? operator2))
          ;The list was of the form (operand c1 c2)
          (simplePrefix lst)
      )

     (if (and (list? operator1) (number? operator2))
          (begin
             (list operand operator2 (processExpression operator1))     
         )
     )
   )

  (define (simplePrefix lst)

       (let (
         (operand (car lst))
         (operator1 (cadr lst))
         (operator2 (caddr lst)))

         (list operator1 operand operator2)
     )

  )

 (display "Please enter a valid s-expression")
 (let ((input (read)))
     (display (simplePrefix input))
 )
```

This code takes and s-expression and converts it based on some rules. One rule should be that the expression (+ (+ 1 2) 2) should return (+ 2 (1 + 2)).

Currently when I call this code with that expression I get back the result "#undef>" but I have no idea why. The code should call the simplePrefix function on the (+ 1 2) part of the expression and return (1 + 2) but it does not. Does anyone understand why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of

```
(if condition
   something)
```

is undefined if **condition** is false, because there's no **else** part in the **if** form.  In the R5RS version of Scheme, this is stated (emphasis added):

> #### [4.1.5  Conditionals](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-7.html#%25_sec_4.1.5)
>
> syntax: `(if <test> <consequent> <alternate>)`
>   syntax: `(if <test> <consequent>)`
>   Syntax: `<Test>`, `<consequent>`, and `<alternate>` may be arbitrary expressions.
>
> Semantics: An if expression is evaluated as follows: first, <test> is evaluated. If it yields a true value (see section
>   6.3.1), then <consequent> is evaluated and its value(s) is(are) returned. Otherwise <alternate> is evaluated and its value(s)
>   is(are) returned. **If <test> yields a false value and no
>   <alternate> is specified, then the result of the expression is
>   unspecified.**
>
> ```
> (if (> 3 2) 'yes 'no)                   ===>  yes
> (if (> 2 3) 'yes 'no)                   ===>  no
> (if (> 3 2)
>     (- 3 2)
>     (+ 3 2))                            ===>  1
> ```

Some Scheme-like languages (e.g., Racket) will actually warn you if you try this:

```
Welcome to Racket v6.1.
> (if #t
    (display "hello"))
stdin::1: if: missing an "else" expression
  in: (if #t (display "hello"))
  context...:
```

In Common Lisp, the else part is optional, and defined to be **nil** if not provided:

```
This is SBCL 1.2.4.58-96f645d, an implementation of ANSI Common Lisp.
More information about SBCL is available at <http://www.sbcl.org/>.
* (if t
    (print 'hello))

HELLO 
HELLO
* (if nil
    (print 'hello))

NIL
```

Comment: From R6RS onwards, the correct way to do side-effecting conditionals is to use `when` and `unless`. `if` should strictly only be used for situations where you'd use the conditional operator (`?:`) in C-style languages.

Answer (score 0):

The expression

```
(if condition result)
```

is *not* equivalent to

```
if condition
   return result
```

in other languages.
It doesn't return a value, it has a value. 
If the condition is false, that value is undefined.
If it is followed by other expressions in a sequence, the value is ignored and the following expressions are evaluated.

The result of evaluating a function application is the value of the last expression in the function's body

```
(define (foo) 
  (if (= 1 1)
      "one is one")
  "I am still here")


> (foo)
"I am still here"
```

These two added together lead to the error you're experiencing.